# Ruby - Updating One Class Instance Inadvertently Updates Another Class Instance As Well

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to build a simple tic tac toe program in Ruby. I'm running into a problem where calling a method on one class instance updates another class instance. The problem is in my Game class which is shown below:

```
class Game
    attr_accessor :turn_count, :all_positions_occupied, :winner, :rows, :columns, :diagonals

    def initialize
        @turn_count = 0

        @all_positions_occupied =  {1 => "*", 2 => "*", 3 => "*",
                                    4 => "*", 5 => "*", 6 => "*",
                                    7 => "*", 8 => "*", 9 => "*"}

        @winner = nil

        @rows = { 1 => [1, 2, 3], 2 => [4, 5, 6], 3 => [7, 8, 9] }

        @columns = { 1 => [1, 4, 7], 2 => [2, 5, 8], 3 => [3, 6, 9] }

        @diagonals = { 1 => [1, 5, 9], 2 => [3, 5, 7] } 
    end

    def refresh_line(line, item, symbol)
        line.each do |key, value|
            if value.include?(item)
                value[(value.index(item))] = symbol
            end
        end
    end

    def occupy_selected(selection, symbol)
        @all_positions_occupied[selection] = symbol 

        # Refresh rows, columns, and diagonals

        refresh_line(@rows, selection, symbol)
        refresh_line(@columns, selection, symbol)
        refresh_line(@diagonals, selection, symbol)
    end

    def copy_onto_virtual_board(virtual_game)
        virtual_game.all_positions_occupied = @all_positions_occupied.clone
        virtual_game.rows = @rows.clone
        virtual_game.columns = @columns.clone
        virtual_game.diagonals = @diagonals.clone
    end
end
```

I am trying to create computer behavior that tries to block the player from winning. In my main code, I want to create a "real_game" and a "virtual_game". Whenever it is the computer's turn to go, I want to run the following method:

```
def block_win(virtual_game)
        # Copy Real Board Onto Virtual Board Using 'copy_onto_virtual_board(virtual_game)'
        # Create Array of Available Positions
        # Cycle Through Array of Available -> 'available_positions.each do |position|'
            # Occupy 'position' on the Virtual Board with 'X' using 'occupy_selected(position, 'X')
            # If 'virtual_game.check_for_winner' is not nil
                # Have Computer Occupy that Position with 'O', effectively blocking 'X' from taking that position and winning
            # Else
                # Re-Copy Real Board Onto the Virtual Board Using 'copy_onto_virtual_board(virtual_game)' 
    end
```

However, once I use `real_game.copy_onto_virtual_board(virtual_game)`, the `real_game` and `virtual_game` somehow become linked so that whenever I use `occupy_selected(position, "X")` on the virtual_game, it applies the same method to real_game as well. This defeats the whole purpose of having a virtual_game separate from the real_game. As long as I don't use the `copy_onto_virtual_board` method, the two games behave separately.

Any ideas as to why this might be happening? I know this is a convoluted explanation, so please let me know whatever other information you may need.

Thanks for the help.

UPDATE -----------

Based on answer given by engineersmnky below, I updated the following method:

```
def copy_onto_virtual_board(virtual_game)
        virtual_game.all_positions_occupied = @all_positions_occupied.clone
        virtual_game.rows = @rows.keys.zip(@rows.values.map(&:clone)).to_h
        virtual_game.columns = @columns.keys.zip(@columns.values.map(&:clone)).to_h
        virtual_game.diagonals = @diagonals.keys.zip(@diagonals.values.map(&:clone)).to_h
end
```

The block_win method is set up to return the blocking position if there is one. Otherwise it returns a random position based on the available_positions array.

Comment: Narrow down the code to pinpoint the part relevant to your question. I don't feel like reading it.

Comment: I think you issue is due to shallow copying where the arrays contained in your Hashes (`@rows`,`@columns`,`@diagonals`) still retain their references. maybe try something like `@rows.keys.zip(@rows.values.map(&:clone)).to_h` this will clone the inner `Array` meaning changes in the "virtual_game" should not impact the "real_game"

Comment: @engineersmnky, that worked perfectly! Thank you. Now I just need to understand what that code is actually doing. I'll look through the documentation for that.

Comment: @sawa, sorry for the code dump. The way the class is set up, there are a lot of methods that touch other methods. I had no clue where the problem was coming from, so I included all of the methods that I thought would be relevant. Sorry for the inefficiency.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is that you are not deep-copying the hashes. It means that by using `#clone`, your creating a new hash with keys pointing to the same arrays.

You can make deep copies in ruby with `Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(hash))` instead of `hash.clone`. This creates full copies of all objects referenced.

But I must not recommend it, and encourage you to review your design so that you don't need.